# FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. com/yammer/metrics/core/MetricsRegistry

Tags: hive, hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

We facing some issue in beeline while we connecting via beeline to hbase table. We have two hiveserver2, one of the node we got this error like:

```
INFO  : Query ID = hive_20190719154444_babd2ce5-4d41-400b-9be5-313acaffc9bf
INFO  : Total jobs = 1
INFO  : Launching Job 1 out of 1
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:MAPRED] in serial mode
INFO  : Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. com/yammer/metrics/core/MetricsRegistry
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20190719154444_babd2ce5-4d41-400b-9be5-313acaffc9bf); Time taken: 0.072 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. com/yammer/metrics/core/MetricsRegistry (state=08S01,code=-101)
```

hiveserver2 logs:

```
2019-07-19 15:44:11,760 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-74]: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.
2019-07-19 15:44:11,760 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-74]: Error in executeTask
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/MetricsRegistry
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.addHBaseDependencyJars(TableMapReduceUtil.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(TableMapReduceUtil.java:827)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.configureJobConf(HBaseStorageHandler.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PlanUtils.configureJobConf(PlanUtils.java:848)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork.configureJobConf(MapWork.java:518)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapredWork.configureJobConf(MapredWork.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2052)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1280)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:236)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$300(SQLOperation.java:89)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$3$1.run(SQLOperation.java:301)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$3.run(SQLOperation.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-07-19 15:44:11,761 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-74]: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. com/yammer/metrics/core/MetricsRegistry
2019-07-19 15:44:11,761 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-74]: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1563543851689 end=1563543851761 duration=72 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2019-07-19 15:44:11,761 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-74]: Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20190719154444_babd2ce5-4d41-400b-9be5-313acaffc9bf); Time taken: 0.072 seconds
2019-07-19 15:44:11,761 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-74]: <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2019-07-19 15:44:11,777 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-74]: </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1563543851761 end=1563543851777 duration=16 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2019-07-19 15:44:11,787 ERROR org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-74]: Error running hive query:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. com/yammer/metrics/core/MetricsRegistry
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:400)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:238)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$300(SQLOperation.java:89)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$3$1.run(SQLOperation.java:301)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$3.run(SQLOperation.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/MetricsRegistry
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.addHBaseDependencyJars(TableMapReduceUtil.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(TableMapReduceUtil.java:827)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.configureJobConf(HBaseStorageHandler.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PlanUtils.configureJobConf(PlanUtils.java:848)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork.configureJobConf(MapWork.java:518)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapredWork.configureJobConf(MapredWork.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2052)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1280)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:236)
        ... 11 more
2019-07-19 15:44:11,800 INFO  org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager: [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-41]: Closing operation: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=bb82c5fc-7fa0-499d-8036-55d44e4611ae]
```

Comment: You have a "NoClassDefFoundError". You need to add that specific jar to your dependencies. See also [a similar error for sqoop](http://community.hortonworks.com/answers/36899/view.html)

Comment: Hi, The issue has been resolved after adding the specific jar.