# select count(*) from tab org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. org/apache/hadoop/metrics/Updater

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting this error from hive. any idea how to fix it?

`hive> select count(*) from indiv;`

```
Query ID = EMMAdmin_20200108131538_4ab7dc88-8e88-4a74-b074-ff6bd058886e
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. org/apache/hadoop/metrics/Updater
hive>
```

Comment: Is this a question? It seems like you are trying to fix an error.

Comment: Try maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114404/failed-execution-error-return-code-101-from-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-exec-mr